# How to retrieve a Lync conversation with a specific user

Tags: api, lync

I would like to check if a Lync conversation with a specific user already exists. I am using the Lync 2010 API.
I think this can be done by iterating the `Conversations` collection returned from the `Conversations` property of `ConversatinManager`. However, I am not sure this is the best way (since my application might handle many conversations at the same time) and that there is no other more efficient way to do so.

Help anyone?

Comment: Do you mean an active conversation, or a stored one (persistent chat). And AudioVideo, InstantMessage, or both?

Answer (score 1):

It's best to keep your own list of conversations. By subscribing to the [ConversationAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.conversationmanager.conversationadded_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt.aspx) and [ConversationRemoved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.conversationmanager.conversationremoved_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt) events, you can keep a collection of conversations, keyed by the SIP address of the user. That way you'll always know for sure.

If you only care about specific types of conversations - such as audio/video for example - be aware of modality changes on existing conversations, such as when a user starts a conversatinon on IM, but then upscales to AV. That won't be classed as a new conversation. I've blogged about handling this here: [Detecting Modality Changes on Existing Conversations](http://thoughtstuff.co.uk/2012/07/detecting-modality-change-on-existing-conversations/).

Hope this helps.